# uwp - Boolean to visibility converter doesn't work

Tags: mvvm, uwp, viewmodel, uwp-xaml, converters

I don't understand why something so simple cause me this much trouble but still.
I have this converter:

```cs
public class BoolToVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

and this view model:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isHowToVisibile;

    public bool IsHowToVisible
    {
        get { return isHowToVisibile; }
        set { isHowToVisibile = value; Notify(nameof(IsHowToVisible)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void ShowHowTo()
    {
        IsHowToVisible = true;
    }
}
```

In the XAML I have a button that activate `ShowHowTo` and change `IsHowToVisible` to `true`,
and a `StackPanel` that its visibility I bind to the view model property `IsHowToVisible`, it looks like this:

```xml
<AppBarButton Label="How To Play" Icon="Help" Click="{x:Bind loginViewModel.ShowHowTo}"/>

<StackPanel Name="HowTo" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="6" Visibility="{x:Bind loginViewModel.IsHowToVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToVis},Mode=OneWay}">
    <Button Name="CloseHowTo" Content="Close" Click="CloseHowTo_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
    <Image  Source="Assets/HowTo.jpg"  Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

XAML knows the converter by this:

```xml
xmlns:con="using:MyApp.Converters"

<Page.Resources>
    <con:BoolToVisibleConverter x:Key="boolToVis"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

The button works. Walking with the debugger shows that the property in the view model do change to `true`, and the `PropertyChanged` event does fire. But that's it. I put a break point in the converter and it doesn't get there.

I tried to rebuild and deploy, change the mode to `Mode=TwoWay`, nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `x:Bind` default to `OneTime`, evaluated only once. If the initial value of the property is true, will converter be called and convert `true` to `Visible`? If it does, the converter is working as expected. Then change the mode to `OneWay` or `TwoWay` - your code is working in either case.

Answer (score 6):

In my test, your above code works well, please make sure your can **Go to Definition (or F12)** when you focus on the `<con:BoolToVisibleConverter />` xaml.

On the other way, if your app target on Windows 10 version 1607 and later, you can delete your `BoolToVisibleConverter` code and don't need to use the Convert in your xaml. Since starting in Windows 10, version 1607, the XAML framework provides a built in Boolean to Visibility converter. The converter maps true to the Visible enumeration value and false to Collapsed so you can bind a Visibility property to a Boolean without creating a converter. Note that this is not a feature of function binding, only property binding. To use the built in converter, your app's minimum target SDK version must be 14393 or later. You can't use it when your app targets earlier versions of Windows 10.

If you still have this issue, you can create a minimal sample that could reproduce it.